# How to use Diff function

Tags: matlab

I'm doing an algorithm and at some point I have to calculate the derivative of a function, I tried to use `diff` but it didn't work.

I have the function defined like this:

```
function y = funcionF(x)
   y = x^3 - 3*x^2 -10;
end
```

I tried `diff(funcionF)` but I get this error:

> Not enough input arguments.

Is there a way to make it work or is mandatory to use a Symbolic Function?

Answer (score 1):

https://au.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/differentiation.html

You need to define the symbols using `syms` which requires the Symbolic Math Toolbox, which I don't have, but this should work (according to the documentation):

```
>> syms x
>> f = x^3 - 3*x^2 - 10;
>> diff(f)
```

should give you something like

```
ans = 
3*x^2-6*x
```